# Grails 2.3.8 application integration test fails

Tags: grails

I have a simple grails app I started to write. So far I only have a few domain classes, no other artefacts. Yesterday I ran the only one integration test I have and it passed. Today when I run it I get this output:

```
2015-04-23 11:07:37,000 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: create table or
der (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, customer_id bigi
nt not null, date_created timestamp not null, total float not null, primary key (id))
Error |
2015-04-23 11:07:37,002 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Syntax error in SQL statement
 "CREATE TABLE ORDER[*] (ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, VERSION BIGINT NOT NU
LL, CUSTOMER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, DATE_CREATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, TOTAL FLOAT NOT NULL, PR
IMARY KEY (ID)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table order (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, c
ustomer_id bigint not null, date_created timestamp not null, total float not null, primary
 key (id)) [42001-173]
Error |
2015-04-23 11:07:37,004 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table ord
er add constraint FK651874E6A961CB1 foreign key (customer_id) references customer
Error |
2015-04-23 11:07:37,004 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Syntax error in SQL statement
 "ALTER TABLE ORDER[*] ADD CONSTRAINT FK651874E6A961CB1 FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENC
ES CUSTOMER "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table order add constraint FK651874E6A961CB1 foreign key (customer_id) references cu
stomer [42001-173]
Error |
2015-04-23 11:07:37,005 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table ord
er_item add constraint FK2D110D6455275AA3 foreign key (order_id) references order
Error |
2015-04-23 11:07:37,005 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Syntax error in SQL statement
 "ALTER TABLE ORDER_ITEM ADD CONSTRAINT FK2D110D6455275AA3 FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENC
ES ORDER[*] "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table order_item add constraint FK2D110D6455275AA3 foreign key (order_id) references
 order [42001-173]
.......
|Compiling 1 source files
..
|Tests PASSED - view reports in C:\Users
```

And when I open the HTML test results page, it says no tests were executed. I even tried `grails clean-all`. At this point my project is just starting so I can easily create a new app and copy my code over to that but I would love to know what is wrong with this app. Yesterday this test ran fine and passed, all I did was close my IDE and started it again today. I even closed the ide and tried to run the test from the command prompt with same bad results.

In case anyone wants to see the code, it's [here](https://github.com/ComCoSolutions/rickshaw/tree/test-cases)

Comment: Modify `dbCreate = "update"` to `dbCreate = "create-drop"` in `DataSource.groovy` under test environment. Precisely [here](https://github.com/ComCoSolutions/rickshaw/blob/test-cases/grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy#L26).

Comment: @dmahapatro Thank you, upon doing that, my integration test now runs. But all the error messages from the logger as pasted above are still printing. I have seen elsewhere that this is a known bug, if this is so is there any way to suppress this output?

Comment: No I suppose, although these logs does not hamper. Best course of action would be to upgrade to Grails 2.4.5 or 2.5.0, if feasible, at this point of time.

Comment: @dmahapatro Ok thanks, I'd be glad to mark as answer if you want to post your first comment as answer since that did solve the issue of not running the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying `dbCreate = "update"` to `dbCreate = "create-drop"` in `DataSource.groovy` under test environment (precisely [here](https://github.com/ComCoSolutions/rickshaw/blob/test-cases/grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy#L26)) should fix this issue.

Basically it would recreate db in between tests which would be a cleaner approach during tests.

Comment: correct, because that will be under `test { }` environment.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so but better to confirm.